# Which statistical analysis should I use for my research proposal?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, manova

So I'm designing a study but not sure which statistical test to use.

Participants will be split into three groups - A, B, and C.

For all participants, I will first conduct a questionnaire and will use the results to rank each participant from 1-10 based on how much their answers demonstrate a particular behaviour. I will follow up by conducting a neuroimaging test on the same participants, which will give a binary Yes/No result. The outcome of the neuroimaging test should depend on the result of the questionnaire (the higher the rank, the more likely Yes) although this will not definitely be the case if there are other factors at play. I am hypothesising that people in study group A will have a higher score on the questionnaire, and will be more likely Yes in the neuroimaging test.

What statistical test/model would be the best for this? Or should it be two separate tests? I have confused myself with the three categories and the relationship between the two dependent variable (I'm thinking some kind of model with a test for interaction between them?). I will be doing the analysis in R. Any help would be really appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Since your sample size is likely to be small, coding the neuroimaging output as binary is probably too low in terms of information content for your sample size to give you enough power/precision.  The neuroimage needs to be precisely quantified to have more hope for the study.  And how are you going to rank the participants?  Is it an reproducible objective method that will not give you too many "investigator degrees of freedom"?

Comment: Thanks! So there should be around 50 participants. the fMRI will be looking for activation of a region of the brain (according to a pre-defined threshold), and the ranked questionnaire will not be created by myself but one commonly used in the field, so I am fairly confident in its objectivity.